# Return all SSJS property value pairs for object?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ssjs, landing-page

I'm looking for one of two things.

1. A complete reference guide for all SFMC SSJS objects, or
2. A way to return all contents of an object so I can see what I need to use.

For an example, I've been following [this guide](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/98330/how-can-i-obtain-the-status-of-an-automation-in-a-business-unit-using-ampscript?rq=1) to show the status of an automation. It uses the ProgramID, CustomerKey, Status. What I'd also like to do is return the last date the automation was run, or any further information about it.

The problem is, I don't even know if this property exists in the object, or what else it contains that I can search for. Is there a library somewhere out there where I can look up all of the properties for particular SFMC objects, or a way I can print the full object, with all property/value pairs, so I can see what it contains?

Answer (score 1):

This is not dependant on SSJS, but instead the API objects. To get a full list of available properties/attributes on the API Objects related [go here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/automation.htm)

Screen shot showing the properties:

[image]

The Object you may want to investigate using instead of 'Automation' is the '[AutomationInstance](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/automationinstance.htm)' object. This appears to have a property near what you want (StatusLastUpdate).

---

**EDIT**
Status should mimic what is shown in the Automation Object, which is below:

[image: Status ScreenShot]

Comment: Thanks, managed to be able to pull a list of all automations of a certain status. Now trying a retrieve from AutomationInstance but not sure what to search on. It times out if I try 'Modified Date = Now()' and claims there is no such column as 'AutomationID' any idea how to just pull the latest one or at least get some idea of what sort of values 'Status' holds? Thanks!

Comment: @TCassa edited my answer to show different values status should hold

Comment: Thanks, but I get 'no rows found' for all of those statuses unfortunately.