# Create a Automation Studio Dashboard on a Marketing Cloud Cloud Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ssjs, marketingcloudapi

I Want to Create a dashboard where all Automations and there status in the Account is displayed. [old post on the topic](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/98330/how-can-i-obtain-the-status-of-an-automation-in-a-business-unit-using-ampscript)

I Want to push all Automation object data to a data extension. This can only be accomplished with the SOAP API or with SSJS script in Automation Studio Activity Right? I want to create A landingpage with AMPscript similar to the possibillities with the _Journey data view, which was easier to create with AMPscript and a data extension. Do you have any tips to set this up or gain the knowledge i need to create this Dashboard.

Does someone have any example for the above solution in combination with a data extension.

Comment: You just want the dash to show all the automatons and current status? No other info? Just want to clarify the ask.

Comment: Hi @Gortonington Indeed. I want a visual representation of the current Automation Status, in a table if possible. I Dont want to be able to adjust an Automation via the dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the easiest way to attain this is via a SOAP call to the [Automation Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/automation.htm).

Below is a sample SOAP envelope that should return all of your automations and their corresponding Statuses:

```
  <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
  <RetrieveRequest>
        <ObjectType>Automation</ObjectType>
        <Properties>Name</Properties>
        <Properties>Status</Properties>
        <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
            <Property>Status</Property>
            <SimpleOperator>IN</SimpleOperator>
            <Value>-1</Value>
            <Value>0</Value>
            <Value>1</Value>
            <Value>2</Value>
            <Value>3</Value>
            <Value>4</Value>
            <Value>5</Value>
            <Value>6</Value>
            <Value>7</Value>
            <Value>8</Value>
        </Filter>
  </RetrieveRequest>
  </RetrieveRequestMsg>
```

Sample Results:

```
   <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
        <RequestID>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</RequestID>
        <Results xsi:type="Automation">
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
            <Name>Automation1</Name>
            <Status>2</Status>
        </Results>
        <Results xsi:type="Automation">
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
            <Name>Automation2</Name>
            <Status>2</Status>
        </Results>
    </RetrieveResponseMsg>
```

If you wish to retrieve all available properties from this object outside of just Name/Status, you can utilize the `*` wildcard character in this Object.  Not all of the SFMC SOAP objects accept this character, only a very few.

For reference, here is a chart of what each status number equals:

[image]

The SOAP envelopes should be able to be translated into WSProxy or SSJS/AMPscript API calls fairly easily and be easily parsed.

For example, the following WSProxy should do it:

```
<script runat="server">

Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

  var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

  var cols = ["Name","Status"];
  var filter = {
      Property: "Status",
      SimpleOperator: "IN",
      Value: [-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
  };
  var res = prox.retrieve("Automation", cols, filter);

</script>
```

You then just parse the returned JSON in `res` to get the info you want to reference.